# MAX with UNION subquery does not produce desired results

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, max, union

I'm having a trouble with getting the max date from a UNION subquery. My code looks like this:

```
SELECT MX.LOCATION AS LOC, MAX(MX.TIMESTAMP) AS TIME
FROM

  (SELECT TAB1.LOCATION AS LOCATION, TAB2.TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP
   FROM TABLE1 TAB1
   JOIN TABLE2 TAB2 ON TAB1.ID=TAB2.ID
   WHERE TAB2.COMPANY =3

   UNION

   SELECT TAB3.LOCATION AS LOCATION, TAB2.TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP
   FROM TABLE3 TAB3
   WHERE TAB3.COMPANY = 3) MX

GROUP BY MX.LOCATION
```

Problem occurs when I have the same location in two queries joined by UNION.
What I'm getting is MAX timestamp from the 1st query and the 2nd. What I want is simply MAX for each location - not both of them.

**SAMPLE DATA. OUTPUT OF UNION STATEMENT. TABLE COLUMN ONLY INDICATES DATASET ROWS BELONG TO**

```
LOCATION  TIMESTAMP        TABLE
855       2017-07-29 13:48 TAB1
856       2017-07-28 14:50 TAB1
855       2017-07-29 11:48 TAB2

RESULT
LOCATION  TIMESTAMP
855       2017-07-29 11:48
855       2017-07-29 13:48
856       2017-07-28 14:50
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. Since you have `GROUP BY MX.LOCATION` you must get each location once with its max timestamp.

Comment: Group by clause will remove the lower timestamp, so you must be getting only location with maximum timestamp. As @GordonLinoff suggested, Please post some sample data and expected result.

Comment: @forpas in theory yes, it's my first time doing an aggregate with UNION and it looks strange. As I said it only occurs when the same location is in two tables joined by UNION

Comment: If you get 2 rows for the same location then it is not the same location. Check for spaces at the end or any unprintable chars.

Comment: The first select statement in the sub-query is missing a FROM clause as well as your TAB1.

Comment: @forpas it is the same because my tool groups it visually and recognizes it as the same location

Comment: What kind of tool `groups it visually`?

Comment: @forpas AQT, see my answer. There were indeed spaces but the tool treted is as the same value. Very strange.

Comment: So get rid of that tool.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Some locations had spaces in them. I used TRIM function to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Query can be written following

```
with allTableInformation as (

SELECT tb1.location, tb1.time
from table1 tb1

union
select tb2.location, tb2.time
from table2 tb2

union
select tb3.location, tb3.time
from table3 tb3
) 
select distinct on (location) location, time from allTableInformation 
order by location, time desc
```

You can try query in [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0a2d3288ccacb3da90700ff0b49311cd)